# How to decode a property with type of Array of dictionary in Swift 5 decodable protocol without key?

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary, codable

The below JSON response does not have the key and contents the array of dictionaries.

```
[
  {
    "content": "You can't program the monitor without overriding the mobile SCSI monitor!",
    "media": [
      {
        "title": "Bedfordshire backing up copying",
      }
    ],
    "user": [
      {
        "name": "Ferne",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am trying to decode this JSON using **Decodable** protocol using below struct

```
struct Articles: Decodable {
  var details: ArticleDetails
  
  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
    details = try container.decode(ArticleDetails.self)
  }
}

struct ArticleDetails: Decodable {
  var content: String
  var media: [Media]
  var user: [User]
  
  enum Keys: String, CodingKey {
    case content
    case media
    case user
  }
  
  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Keys.self)
    content = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .content)
    media = try container.decode([Media].self, forKey: .media)
    user = try container.decode([User].self, forKey: .user)
  }
}

struct Media: Decodable {
  var title: String
  
  enum Keys: String, CodingKey {
    case title
  }
  
  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Keys.self)
    title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
  }
}

struct User: Decodable {
  var name: String
  
  enum Keys: String, CodingKey {
    case name
  }
  
  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Keys.self)
    name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
  }
}
```

and decoding the response using below

```
let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Articles.self, from: data)
```

OR

```
let response = try JSONDecoder().decode([ArticleDetails].self, from: data)
```

but getting the error

> "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a string/data
> instead."

How to decode such JSON response which contents array of dictionaries without a key?

Comment: You use a key enum only when you want to change decodable variable names.

Comment: Your data comes as an array.  So the latter is the right one.

Answer (score 1):

Model:

```
struct Articles: Decodable {
    let content: String
    let media: [Media]
    let user: [User]
}

struct Media: Decodable {
    let title: String
}

struct User: Decodable {
    let name: String
}
```

Decoding:

```
do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode([Articles].self, from: data)
    print(response)
} catch { print(error) }
```

(This was already posted in your previous post. Which has been deleted.)

Comment: It looks fine with me.

Comment: @Frankenstein - Previously you have using the codable protocol, which doesn't work as you know and I have already replied to your answer. 
To keep the question clean and answer, I have removed the old question and added new. I hope you will understand the +1 for my question.

Now Your answer really works for me. Thanks :)
Hence upvote for your answer.